# Filebeat to Kafka to Logstash: Tages are not appearing as expected

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to implement Kafka between Filebeat and Logstash.

When sending filebeat to Kafka (it comes in a text format) and same goes to Logstash. For which, I assume, the Logstash is unable to process the input.

Here is the different when the data comes from Kafka, and directly from Filebeat to Logstash.

From Kafka:

```
{
       "message" => "nice",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "kafka-stream"
    ],
    "@timestamp" => 2020-06-30T08:29:29.071Z,
      "@version" => "1"
}
{
       "message" => "{\"@timestamp\":\"2020-06-30T08:34:28.178Z\",\"@metadata\":{\"beat\":\"filebeat\",\"type\":\"_doc\",\"version\":\"7.8.0\"},\"agent\":{\"hostname\":\"Smits-MacBook-Pro.local\",\"ephemeral_id\":\"b9779246-3cc9-408b-83ac-e69eeef3cd28\",\"id\":\"864be1a9-e233-4d41-8624-cf94e916a0b7\",\"name\":\"Smits-MacBook-Pro.local\",\"type\":\"filebeat\",\"version\":\"7.8.0\"},\"log\":{\"offset\":11341,\"file\":{\"path\":\"/Users/Smit/Downloads/chrome/observability/spring_app_log_file.log\"}},\"message\":\"2020-06-30 16:34:20.328  INFO 63741 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-7] c.e.o.controller.HomeController          : AUDIT_LOG >> customer id a8703\",\"tags\":[\"observability\",\"audit\"],\"input\":{\"type\":\"log\"},\"ecs\":{\"version\":\"1.5.0\"},\"host\":{\"name\":\"Smits-MacBook-Pro.local\"}}",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "kafka-stream"
    ],
    "@timestamp" => 2020-06-30T08:34:29.222Z,
      "@version" => "1"
}
```

From Filebeat:

```
{
          "type" => "log",
    "@timestamp" => 2020-06-30T04:37:18.935Z,
      "@version" => "1",
           "log" => {
          "file" => {
            "path" => "/Users/Smit/Downloads/chrome/observability/spring_app_log_file.log"
        },
        "offset" => 10846
    },
         "input" => {
        "type" => "log"
    },
           "ecs" => {
        "version" => "1.5.0"
    },
       "message" => "2020-06-30 12:37:16.900  INFO 63741 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.o.controller.HomeController          : AUDIT_LOG >> customer id d6ebe",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "observability",
        [1] "audit",
        [2] "beats",
        [3] "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
      "hostname" => {
        "name" => "Smits-MacBook-Pro.local"
    },
         "agent" => {
                "type" => "filebeat",
             "version" => "7.8.0",
                "name" => "Smits-MacBook-Pro.local",
            "hostname" => "Smits-MacBook-Pro.local",
        "ephemeral_id" => "1ca4e838-eeaa-4b87-b52a-89fa385865b8",
                  "id" => "864be1a9-e233-4d41-8624-cf94e916a0b7"
    }
}
```

Now, when i visualise the data in Kibana:

Here is the output when log are directly sent from Filebeat to Logstash:

[image]

Here is the output when log are from Filebeat to Kafka to Logstash:

[image]

Let me know if you need any more info.

Also config for each product in ELK is here: https://github.com/shah-smit/observability-spring-demo

Answer (score 0):

When you send logs directly to logstash, you use the beats protocol, that adds some "extra" fields to your event:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/exported-fields-beat-common.html

I'm not really sure about which protocol kafka output uses, but for sure this don't add the beats extra fields.

For this reason, when you send logs to kafka and then read them from logstash, you have fewer fields.